# Regex Expression For Mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, sprinklr

I have data from twitter where I need to find if the word 'off' is present in the tweet but drop those rows where 'off' is present in any twitter handles. These mentions can be anywhere in the entire tweet string and cases like @**off**ersforyou or @gr**off**ers are need to be dropped if 'off' is present anywhere in the mention, ie, anywhere in string between @ and immediate next blank space.

I am using mysql version 8.0.28 (ICU regex flavor).

Comment: *MySQL implements regular expression support using International Components for Unicode (ICU), which provides full Unicode support and is multibyte safe.* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: *and not sure if it is using* Practical check needs in less than a minute.

Comment: I am using 
https://regex101.com/
with PCRE to test the regex but it is not working when I am using the same expression in Mysql Workbench

Comment: Please provide a list of cases to keep/drop.  Start with the samples in Akina's Answer.  Be sure to include any relevant "twitter handles" so we understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"anywhere in string between @ and immediate next blank space" -->

```
 REGEXP "@\\w*off\\w*\\s"
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied from CLI:

```sql
Server version: 8.0.28 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> WITH cte AS ( SELECT '@offersforyou' txt UNION ALL
    ->               SELECT '@groffers' UNION ALL
    ->               SELECT 'offers' UNION ALL
    ->               SELECT 'off word' )
    -> SELECT txt, REGEXP_LIKE(txt, '\\boff\\b') FROM cte;
+---------------+-------------------------------+
| txt           | REGEXP_LIKE(txt, '\\boff\\b') |
+---------------+-------------------------------+
| @offersforyou |                             0 |
| @groffers     |                             0 |
| offers        |                             0 |
| off word      |                             1 |
+---------------+-------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```